# Google maps in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I want to show a simple map for a custom location in my app. Can someone tell me if there is some there alternative that can be used to show maps in a react-native app (react native v0.61) other than `react-native-maps`. Following is the issue that is happening with me when I used `react-native-maps`:

I have been displaying a small map for some particular location. This was achieved through first using the Plugin - `react-native-maps` and then using the following code:

```
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
    style={styles.map}
    region={{
       latitude: latlng.latitude,
       longitude: latlng.longitude,
       latitudeDelta: 0.012,
       longitudeDelta: 0.012,
     }}
>
   <Marker coordinate={{latitude: latlng.latitude, longitude: latlng.longitude}} />    
</MapView>
```

if needed here is the android/build.gradle :

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
        supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0+" // or find latest version
    }
```

This has been working completely fine for the past month. For some reason now, whenever I come to this screen where I display the map, the app crashes. I remove this piece of code and everything works again. I can't seem to understand why this is happening.

Can some please help me.

React native -> v0.61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug with the Google Maps SDK right now:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417

It is causing the crashes.